# CABasicAnimation activity and resources usage with hidden layer

Tags: ios, performance, calayer, quartz-core, cabasicanimation

I add endless rotating animation to view's layer with this code

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:toValue];
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.7;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[animatingView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

In some cases, i need to hide animatingView and keep animation in it layer. What will happen with animation rendering in this case? Will animation in hidden layer consume device's resources?